# How to select the meta tags and get the content value in Cheerio?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I would like to select the meta tag with the `og:title` property and get the content text value from it i.e. `Silver Surfer`, I cannot figure how to approach this in Cheerio

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="SILVER" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.silversurfer.com/surfer.png"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Silver Surfer" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.silversurfer.com" />
```

This is my latest attempt so far
`var title = $('meta[property=og:title]').content`

Comment: If you cannot figure it out, you must have tried a couple of things. Show them.

Comment: Just edited my original post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use attribute css selector and to get the attribute use `Cheerio::attr`.

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load(`
<meta property="og:type" content="SILVER" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.silversurfer.com/surfer.png"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Silver Surfer" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.silversurfer.com" />
`);

$('[property="og:type"]').attr('content');
```

Comment: I wasn't properly loading the content, hence why my approach was not working!